# How to reload a functional component on change of certain value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mobx, mobx-react

I have a functional component and I am having a mobx store.

```
export const Main: () =>
  ({ permissions }) => {
    return useObserver(() => {
      const {
        datastore : {isSyncInProcess }
      } = stores

      const renderSwitch = section => {
        switch (section) {
          case Parent.A:
            if (value) {
              return <B />
            }
            return <C />
          case Parent.D:
            return <E />
          default:
            return <F permissions={permissions} />
        }
      }

      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          { renderSwitch(section) : null}
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    })
  }
```

Here, I have this functional component. Now here I have one observable `isSyncInProcess`, I am trying to achieve is that when this isSyncInProcess gets changed then it should actually reload this component so that whatever the api or query are there in the components of switch should get called again.

How do I fix this ?

I tried

```
React.useEffect(() => {

      },[isSyncInProcess])
```

Comment: The useEffect hook should work assuming the change of `isSyncInProcess` in your store actually triggers a re-render. Does it re-render at all currently when it changes?

Comment: @ganeshk what do you mean by "reload"? You want to remount it? Or just rerender?

Comment: If you don't do an actual read from an observable the component wont get re-rendered. if `isSyncInProcess` is observable and you read from it, the component will re-render once it's changed.